# Azure B2C custom policy Signup Only with Social Signup

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have created a custom policy ([Customised Starter Pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack)) to provide only signup. I don't need any sign in in this policy. This is my OrchestrationSteps

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection"
      ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections.signup">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange"
          TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId"
          TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims"
      CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

My Technical Profile of LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail defined as follows.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
            Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ParagraphType" DefaultValue="--------------------(or)-----------------------" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"
              DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:register_email}"
              AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <!-- <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" /> -->
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ParagraphType" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />

            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
          </DisplayClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ParagraphType" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />

            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

My Technical Profile for Facebook-OAuth is below here.

```
<ClaimsProviders>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <!-- The following Domain element allows this profile to be used if the request comes with domain_hint 
           query string parameter, e.g. domain_hint=facebook.com  -->
      <Domain>facebook.com</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
          <!-- The text in the following DisplayName element is shown to the user on the claims provider 
               selection screen. -->
          <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ProviderName">facebook</Item>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth</Item>
            <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">GET</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>

            <!-- The Facebook required HTTP GET method, but the access token response is in JSON format from 3/27/2017 -->
            <Item Key="AccessTokenResponseFormat">json</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_FacebookSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="first_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="last_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="facebook.com" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

I want to show Facebook Button to my above Local Signup page. To show that, How Can I change my OrchestrationSteps in the above?

[image]

Comment: It is not possible to add identity providers to a self-asserted page (of which sign-up is one). 
You may wish to have a screen prior to this which asks the user if they want to sign-up using Facebook or local account (manually). Note, if you give them the ability to sign-in with facebook you will also need to handle accounts that don't exist in your directory after they have federated.